# Как мне связать цикл If else и onChange?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы определенный код выполнялся только в случае заполнения input. То есть если форма заполнена, то некий код выполняется.Подойдет-ли для этого цикл If else и onChange?Если да, то как это реализовать?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Телефон">
<button class="submit">Отправить</button>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: что за форма ? когда этот загадочный код должен выполняться ?

Comment: Как разница?Я не хочу целиком скидывать весь код, смысла в  этом просто не вижу. Вопрос не в этом: Можно-ли связать заполнение формы с выполнением какого-либо кода?

Comment: ответ - "можно". Если бы вы еще более точную информацию дали, о том когда именно должно что-то там выполняться

Comment: Отредактировал свой вопрос. Вот например, нажимаю я на кнопку с классом "submit" и если форма заполнена выводится сообщение с помощью alert "форма заполнена", если не заполнена соответственно сообщение с текстом, что форма не заполнена. Такое как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам лично использую этот вариант во многих проектах. Обязательным полям добавляем атрибут `required` и если по нажатию на кнопку одно из них не заполнено, выводится сообщение под нужным полем. Плюс в том, что все работает +- на нативных возможностях браузера.

**Pure JS**

```js
let form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
let submitButton = form.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];

submitButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!form.checkValidity()) {
    //alert("Какое-то поле не заполненно");
    form.reportValidity();
  } else {
    alert("Все обязательные поля заполненны");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
  <button class="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**JQ**

```js
let form = $("form");

$(".submit").on("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!form.get(0).checkValidity()) {
    //alert("Какое-то поле не заполненно");
    form.get(0).reportValidity();
  } else {
    alert("Все обязательные поля заполненны");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
  <button class="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: А есть аналог на JQuery?

Comment: @PavelBogdanov обновил ответ